# Would Using the Star Wars typeface for a Website be considered copyright infringement?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, typefaces

My client wants a logo that uses the Star Wars font called Star Jedi, however I'm sure using a Star Wars font would be copyrighted. Please let me know guys. Is the Star Jedi font only for personal use?

Answer (score 1):

The Star Jedi font guide says the following:

> These fonts are freeware. To tell the truth they’re…“e-mailware”: if you like them send me an e-mail.
>   Boba Fonts
>   Davide Canavero canavero [eta] pianeta.net

I could add (somewhere, as I dunno how to do it here) or send you (somehow again) that guide to learn more.

Or you could contact the author to learn the details.

Comment: Would you suggest I use a different typeface, as well tell hime to change his brand name?

Comment: It depends on your client first of all. Some clients can be really stubborn: "I want THIS and basta!" :)
But if you think you should use a different typeface, what should it be? If similar to Star Jedi, I could advice Stormtrooper http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/comicraft/stormtrooper/ (commercial). There is one more called Distant Galaxy (shareware from ShyFonts http://www.shyfoundry.com/index.html, could not find it on MyFonts)

Comment: It says Star Jedi can be used for commercial. Take a look at this linkhttp://www.fontspace.com/boba-fonts/star-jedi